# How to open a file in the same window? (without creating a split)

Tags: vim-windows

Currently I'm using this to open a file in an existing vim instance.

```
gvim --remote-silent some_file.txt
```

While it opens the file as expected, it *sometimes* splits the window.

I'm not sure what logic it uses, but I'd like to be able to tell it *never* to create a new split-window for the new buffer since it means I need to manually delete the new window - which gets annoying.

Comment: Do you have `:set hidden` in your `vimrc`?

Comment: No, but I have: `set nohidden`.

Comment: Well, your "problem" is a direct consequence of `:set nohidden`.

Comment: I've removed `set nohidden` and still had this problem occur. Perhaps nerdtree or some other plugin is messing with my config. (though I don't use so many plugins)

Answer (score 2):

When you use Vim's `--remote` options, it constructs a `:drop` command.

If the specified file is not already open in an existing window, it will be opened in the current window, unless the file currently in that window cannot be `abandon`ed. (i.e. if the current file is modified and you have both `hidden` and `autowrite` options switched off.) In that case, the window is split instead.

Note however, that at some point in the past there was a bug with this behaviour, which was fixed in version 6.1.173:

> When using remote control to edit a position in a file and this file is the current buffer and it's modified, the window is split and the ":drop" command fails.

Answer (score 1):

I use `:enew` when using (n)vim from the terminal.

Comment: `:enew` starts a new buffer in the current window. `:edit[!]` can be used to open any file as a buffer in the current window (also `:buffer` for loading an existing buffer). But the question is about `--remote-silent`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be off from your actual purpose and you may already know what I suggest here, but how about opening the file in a new *tab* from within vim?

`:tabnew some_file.txt`

If some_file.txt exists it will open it in a new tab, if not it will create a new empty file. You navigate from tab to tab with `gt` (move one tab on the right) and `gT` (move the other way).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I use `:open file` to open file in current window. If you want a awesome search and open a file use `telescope` link: https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: No. see `:help :open`.

Answer (score 0):

`:edit some_file.txt` works in nvim, like

`:open some_file.txt` works in vim(/vi?)

which opens `some_file.txt` file in the window where cursor is [without splitting/...]

Comment: it's not `:open`, its `:e`